# Install .NET Framework 2.0 on Embedded XP (Win XPE)

Tags: .net, qfe

I'm trying to install the .Net framework version 2.0 on embedded Windows XP SP2 (aka XPE).

I'm using the XPE specific version of the installer from Microsoft:

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=c4837dad-5719-4b63-8752-cb0a65802329&displaylang=en

When the installation starts it fails with the following error:

QFE Installer -- Error
Cannot connect to the database - please check the database

How can I get .Net 2.0 installed on SPE?

Comment: Congrats, first XPE question!

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so you're running the installer that is updating your XPE development environment, right?  Or are you attempting to run that on a device before you seal it?

You need to run that installer on the workstation that has the XPE dev environment (and database) installed.  The installer is looking for a specific database on a specific instance of Sql Server, so if you have (or somebody else has) changed it, you'll need to read up on how to specify the connection string to use with the installer.

In addition, it's probably trying to connect using your windows account credentials.  Make sure you are able to log on to Sql Server, open the DB with the component definitions, and add records to it.  Alternatively, if you can specify the connection string you can set a Sql login username and password to use.

Profiler is a great tool for troubleshooting the two issues described above.

Once you have the components installed, you'll have to add them to your image, check your dependencies and then build it.

---

If you're trying to just install .NET 2.0 on a machine directly (before you reseal it), you will need the packages for Windows Installer on the machine first.  There might be some other dependencies; I haven't done it in a long time so I can't remember.

The best way to troubleshoot dependencies on an XPE installation is to put ProcessMonitor from Sysinternals on it.  As you run the installer, you'll see where it attempts to find stuff and fails.  Take that information back to your XPE IDE and search your components for those files.  You then have to add the packages containing those files to your image and try again.  Its an arduous process sometimes..,.

Comment: To clarify I'm trying to run the installer directly on the XPE machine. I'm completely new to XPE, and don't have an XPE development environment (it came pre-installed). 

What's the quickest route to getting .Net installed? A quick search didn't turn up an installer for Windows Installer. Thanks!

Comment: Crap.  You're probably missing lots of files you need.  What you're trying to do is VERY hard.  Most likely you'll have to at least install this http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=5A58B56F-60B6-4412-95B9-54D056D6F9F4&displaylang=en

Comment: But you may have to install other stuff as well.  Your only hope is to get ProcessMonitor on that machine and watch the file system during an install attempt.  Read through the log (its going to be MASSIVE) and find the files that are never located (failed attempts not followed by a successful one)

Comment: Google those files and find out what parts of Windows they come with.  You'll have to track down each and every one of them manually.  There is NOTHING easy about this process.  XPE is meant to be minimal, not easily upgradable.

Comment: Yikes, I think I understand what the issues are now. Thanks for the info!

Answer (score 0):

HI, i know how to fix it,

just install futre-pack 2007 for w XP embedded =(.NET framework2.0 included) :D

Answer (score 0):

The Windows XP Embedded Service Pack 2 Feature Pack 2007 is not a stand alone product; it requires the developer to have Windows® Embedded Studio tool suite installed.